# JavaScript - how can i execute a function of iframe, from main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can i execute the button_one() function from main.php ?

Main.php:

```
<b>Main page - for the actions</b>
<div style="position: absolute; right:9%;top:30px;">      
   <input type=button id=b1 />
</div>

<b>Inner page - for the buttons</b>
<iframe id="layer" src="" ></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // by default loaded
  $('#layer').attr('src', "http://localhost/iframepage.php").show();

  // later on click send command to iframe
  $('#b1').click(function() {
      // how to execute the iframepage.php button_one() script from here?
  });
});
</script>
```

iframepage.php:

```
<b>Welcome</b>
<script>
function button_one() {
 alert("button press from main page");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.frames["layer"].window.button_one()
```

But note that this will only work if `iframe` src is on same domain as your executed script ( in your case `localhost` ). Ports should be the same too as the protocol. Otherwise browser will block this behaviour due to security restrictions.

Comment: I am getting this: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://pbx:80" from accessing a frame with origin "http://iiiiii:8080". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. `

Comment: As I have said in my answer, domain, protocol and port's should match. If not there is no way to call function in parent window from iframe due to security issues.

Comment: OK - Thank you, i understood now. That's why was not allowing.

Comment: Will it work if i have: `www.antyrat.com` as main page, and the iframe pages are in : `iframe.antyrat.com` ? (in case of multi-media and voip server lot of bandwidth is related so i wanted to load the iframe from another server which is mine and also from same organisation)

Comment: @YumYumYum yes, but you should add `document.domain= 'antyrat.com';` to both pages in script tag. Then they will look into same main domain and will be able to comunicate between each other. Note that this should be without `www` so all subdomains will work.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
document.getElementById('layer').contentWindow.button_one();
```